# Slicing a dictionary in python below certain key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary of about 20,000,000 items.

```
dict = {"4": 1, "6": 1, "8": 1, "10": 1, "12": 2, "14": 1, "16": 2, "18": 1, "20": 2, "22": 1, "24": 3, "26": 1, "28": 2, ....}
```

Now I want to get a new dictionary containing all the values whose key is under certain value.

Like I want to obtain a new dict.

```
new_dict = {"4": 1, "6": 1, "8": 1, "10": 1, "12": 2, "14": 1, "16": 2, "18": 1, "20": 2, "22": 1}
```

I need a FASTER WAY TO SLICE THE DICTIONARY since I have to deal with large dictionary.

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: What is it that your dictionary is representing?  This isn't going to be fast, so if you can use another data structure that might help.  You could also look into using a database instead.

Comment: You're very demanding but also very unclear for someone that's asking for help. What effort have you actually put into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict` comprehension.

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in dict.items() if int(k) < certain_value}
```

Comment: Note that this may involve converting the key before comparing, since the key is actually a string, and that this conversion will be the rate-limiter.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, yes, good point! I updated my answer.

Comment: you can use http://www.numpy.org/ or to see this useful resource https://d.cxcore.net/Python/Python_Cookbook_3rd_Edition.pdf and look in the part 12.8. Performing Simple Parallel Programming in the CHAPTER 12 Concurrency